# How do I translate empty text of a view?

Tags: views, 6, i18n-l10n

I have created a view with empty text using PHP code. Now, when I try to translate it through the translation interface (admin/build/translate/search), while I find the string (it show up all the PHP code) and translate it (I did it by adding the PHP code again with the translated strings), when I change the language of my site I see nothing. When I come back to English, it showed up correctly.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If this view is showing inside of a block then make sure you have the translation "Make this block translatable" is checked, and what ever language you want to translate to is also checked.
hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No the view isn't inside of a block. I use a page display of the view as a panel pane.

Comment: do you have your text wrapped around t('like this')?